# Enabling debug zones in WinCE 7

Tags: debugging, windows-ce, zone

I'm a newbie. I'm using WinCE 7 VS 2008. My OS is Windows 7. I'd like to enable debug zones using registry. Previously in Windows XP - WinCE 6, I have used it. But, I'm not aware of how to enable debug zones for a specific module, other than programming it in code. I tried adding it as a registry enty,

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\DebugZones]
       "OMAP GPIO"=dword:FFFF
```

where `OMAP GPIO` is the module name.

The dpCurSettings is,

```
DBGPARAM dpCurSettings = {
    L"OMAP GPIO", {
        L"Errors",      L"Warnings",    L"Function",    L"Info",
            L"IST",         L"Undefined",   L"Undefined",   L"Undefined",
            L"Undefined",   L"Undefined",   L"Undefined",   L"Undefined",
            L"Undefined",   L"Undefined",   L"Undefined",   L"Undefined"
    },
    0x0003
};
```

I used this line in my code.

```
DEBUGMSG(ZONE_FUNCTION, (L"DEBUGZONE :+Am3xxGpioInterruptInitialize\r\n"));
```

But, that doesn't work. I checked for a `Pegasus` entry in development workstation registry. But, I couldn't find that also. Please guide me how to do it.

**UPDATE**

Actually, the debug messages and debug zones are in a static library `am3xx_device_gpio.lib`, which is included as `SOURCELIBS` in a dll `am3xx_gpio.dll`

This is because, `am3xx_device_gpio.lib` is a common TI code. The above registry is available only in `am3xx_gpio.dll`

I think due to this only it's not getting printed. What else can be done, now?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the module name is proper? (I guess it is `DLL` name?? `OMAP GPIO.dll`?)

Actually it should enable the debug zones.

Try

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/DEBUGZONES] "OMAP GPIO"=DWORD:FFFF
```

(if OMAP GPIO is module name.)

For more information, please refer to following links:

1. [Debug messages and debug zones in Windows CE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2006/12/18/debug-messages-and-debug-zones-in-windows-ce.aspx)
2. [How To Enable DEBUGZONEs in the Registry?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267296/EN-US)

Comment: I have updated the question with additional findings. Please check it out. Hope you could help me with this.

Comment: whether DLL name is `am3xx_gpio.dll` ?? Then you need to add reg entry as `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/DEBUGZONES] "OMAP GPIO"=DWORD:FFFF` right?? (_I'm not sure.. But please give it a try.. :)_)

Comment: Yes, I tried like that. But, it didn't get displayed. I think, as the debug zones are in a different file, they are not getting displayed (as in UPDATE). What else could I try now?